# Linking the answers of one list into another

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, lookup-column

I have 2 SharePoint lists, a List A  and a List B. If someone Adds a new item, on List A, I would like certain columns to be able to populate in List B.

For instance, List A has a question that is similar to a column in List B. How can I have it so that List B (when I click add a new item) pulls info from a specific "item" from list A.

I do not have SPD but is it possible to use lookup or a workflow? How could I do this?

Comment: Would you mind providing a few more details with an actual example. I am not sure if you want to update existing items in List B when you add a new item to List A, or if you want to display items from List A in a drop-down field when you create a new item in List B?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I'm fairly new to SharePoint. I first add a new item in  Custom List A which has similar columns in List B. After I finish answering the columns in List A, I then go to Custom List B to fill out that form as well. Can I have it so info from a completed item in List A appear in List B.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to move items from List A to List B once all columns have been filled in / answered in List A. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You can use a workflow on List A with the `Create Item` action where you can specify List B and the fields you want to set in List B from List A. The workflow can be started manually once all columns are filled in. Or you can have the workflow start automatically when a new item is created/updated in List A, but you need to make sure you tell the workflow to pause until a certain criteria is met (for example, pause until a specific column has been filled in).

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to make use of Event Receivers. Apply a event receiver on the list you want to monitor and write the code to shift/ fill data into the destination list.